# Cross-Origin Request Blocked in PHP and JavaScript

Tags: javascript, php, cors

i'm trying to send a post request to using javascript to this php code, but i get this error:

> Cross-Origin Request Blocked: The Same Origin Policy disallows reading the remote resource at "the url of my web app". (Reason: CORS request did not succeed). Status code: (null).

That's my js code:

```
const url = 'https://opecart9349.000webhostapp.com/unzipper/opencart/index.php?route=customapi/test';

fetch(url, {
  method: 'POST',
  headers: {
    'Content-Type': 'application/json',
  },
})
  .then(response => response.json())
  .then(data => {
    // Handle the response data
    console.log(data);
  })
  .catch(error => {
    // Handle any errors
    console.error('Error:', error);
  });
```

and that's my php code:

```
<?php
class ControllerCustomapiTest extends Controller {
    public function index() {
        
        header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *');
        header('Access-Control-Allow-Methods: GET, POST, OPTIONS, PUT, DELETE');
        header('Access-Control-Allow-Headers: Content-Type, Authorization, X-Requested-With');
        
        header('Content-Type: application/json');

        $response = array('success' => true);

        echo json_encode($response);
    }
}
?>
```

Comment: `Status code: (null).` suggests the web page is `file:///` rather than `https://` - but that URL you're fetching returns `access-control-allow-methods: GET, POST, OPTIONS`  and `Access-Control-Allow-Headers: Content-Type` - so that's odd your PHP isn't sending what you want it to send

Comment: Within the `options` you pass to the `fetch` function you can add the `mode: "cors"` the stated endpoint does have the correct headers being set

Comment: I think it's the fact that you're setting a content-type, with no content

Comment: @ProfessorAbronsius - `you can add the mode: "cors"` I believe that's the default mode for cross origin requests

Comment: @JaromandaX - it does appear to work without that so you are most likely 100% correct ~ only when adding the `headers` to the options does it go haywire

Comment: yeah, I mean why tell the server you're sending "application/json", and then send an empty request body - seems doomed to failure :p

Comment: `notice the empty data object` yes, that's an empty `options` parameter ... not content as such, and `,..` makes zero sense since fetch only takes 1 or 2 arguments, never more - not sure why you're trying to teach me about how fetch works, I'm not the OP, and I don't struggle with how fetch works, but thanks for the uncorrection

Answer (score 1):

Access-Control-Allow-Origin: Not all browsers support the * value. In the * field, enter the domain name you sent the request to.

Also OK! for Options type requests! You have to send the answer.

```
if (isset($_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'])) {
    // Decide if the origin in $_SERVER['HTTP_ORIGIN'] is one
    // you want to allow, and if so:
    header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin: http://localhost:4200");
    header('Access-Control-Allow-Credentials: true');
    header('Access-Control-Max-Age: 86400');    // cache for 1 day
}

// Access-Control headers are received during OPTIONS requests
if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'OPTIONS') {

    if (isset($_SERVER['HTTP_ACCESS_CONTROL_REQUEST_METHOD']))
        header("Access-Control-Allow-Methods: GET, POST, PUT, PATCH, OPTIONS");

    if (isset($_SERVER['HTTP_ACCESS_CONTROL_REQUEST_HEADERS']))
        header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers: {$_SERVER['HTTP_ACCESS_CONTROL_REQUEST_HEADERS']}");
    die('OK!');
}
```

Comment: All modern browsers support `*` as a value for the `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` header. However, that value is incompatible with credentialed requests.

Comment: Also, be careful: not all `OPTIONS` requests are preflight requests.